# Help with correcting a simple example on FourierCoefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am learning `FourierCoefficient` and trying to plot `Cos` with it.

1. Let us find it Fourier coefficients with `FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, n]`

   $\begin{array}{cc}
    \{ & 
   \begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{1}{2} & n=-1\lor n=1 \\
    0 & \text{True} \\
   \end{array}
    \\
   \end{array}$
2. I want to use 16 Fourier modes to approximate `Cos`:

   ```
   nn = 16;

   FTcoeffTab = Table[FTcoeff[m] == (KroneckerDelta[m, 1] + KroneckerDelta[m, -1])/2, {m, -nn/2, nn/2-1, 1}]
   ```
3. Construst the Fourier expansion of `Cos` and plot:

   ```
   FT[x_] := Sum[FTcoeff[k]*Exp[I k x], {k, -nn/2, nn/2-1}]

   Plot[FT[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
   ```

But it gives me a null plot. Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: `FTcoeff[m_] := (KroneckerDelta[m, 1] + KroneckerDelta[m, -1])/2`, no  need for `Table`. Then `FT[x_]:=...` and `Plot`.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is actually the same as the answer by @Ulrich Neumann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
FTcoeff[m_] := (KroneckerDelta[m, 1] + KroneckerDelta[m, -1])/2
```

without Table!

```
FT[x_, n _] := Sum[FTcoeff[k]*Exp[I k x], {k, -n /2, n /2 }]
Plot[FT[x, nn] // Evaluate, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]